# "Invalid argument" error when trying to back up to a Windows share

Tags: samba, deja-dup

I am trying to use deja-dup to back up my Ubuntu server to a windows shared drive.  I have entered the needed information however,I keep getting "Invalid argument".

How to use deja-dup with Windows Share?
INFO:  Ubuntu 11.10
Back up to: Windows Shared server.

any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please send us more information.

- How do you have configure deja-dup? Paste some screenshots
- What version of deja-dup do you use?
- Can you access Windows's Share? try with smb://ip__win_share/share Is
  it mounted correctly? Do you use the same credentials?
- "Invalid argument" is a poor log error, can you paste all the
  text from deja-dup window?
- What do you see with this command? sudo deja-dup

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error when backing up to a Windows shared drive (samba on a NAS).

I fixed it with running disk repair on the NAS. I guess something was wrong with the file system on the disk attached to NAS.